# Python's 'input' function does not read non-ascii characters (EOFError)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, input, non-ascii-characters

When I run `python nonascii.py` on my Windows cmd with `chcp 65001`, and input a non-ascii character like ť,č,š,ľ,ž,ý,etc., I get `EOFError` because of the first line.

nonascii.py

```
nonascii = input('Type in a non-ascii character (try e.g. ž): ')
print(nonascii)
```

What shall I do so that the printed output == input?

Comment: Can you use raw_input?

Comment: @DennyWeinberg This is Python 3.x...

Comment: @DennyWeinberg: No, because this is Python 3. `input()` in 3 is the same thing as `raw_input()` in 2.

Comment: Could you try this with Python 3.6 instead? It has re-worked console I/O.

Comment: What is 'chcp 65001'?

Comment: @user2864740: the Windows UTF-8 codepage.